# Using Linq to Entities to get a list of roles that a user has with a self join

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to build a dynamic menu that uses Identity 2.0 roles to define what menu items the user should see. I am very new to C# and need some help please!

For the purpose of what I am doing, I am thinking of a Role as a Menu Item that a user can either see or not depending on the roles assigned to them. I have two levels of Menu Items- the parent menu item (such as "Reports" and the sub menu items (such as "Order Reports", "Receipt Reports" etc).

So my `ApplicationRole` class looks like this:

```
public string Description { get; set; }
public string MenuTitle {get;set;}
public string MenuIcon { get; set; }
public string ControllerName { get; set; }
public string ActionName { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationRole ParentRole { get; set; }
```

I will only store roles against the user whereby the ParentRole is not null. I want to know retrieve this list of roles for the logged in user and render the menu.

So, the logic is going to be something like:

1. Get a list of all Menu Items (roles) that the user has assigned against them.
2. Using this list, use the `ParentRole` to get a distinct list of parent roles (the top level of the menu).
3. Using these 2 lists, populate my View Model below:

   ```
   public class NavigationViewModel
   {
   public int MenuId { get; set; }
   public string MenuName { get; set; }
   public string ControllerName { get; set; }
   public string ActionName { get; set; }
   public string MenuIcon { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<NavigationViewModel> ChildMenuItems { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Basically, I am creating a menu that has a top level menu and a sub-menu.

My problem is, is that I really don't know where to start in terms of querying the database.
Ideally, I would like a query that does a self join onto the Role table to get the Parent Role in the same query, however I'm brand new to C# and Linq and do not know where to start.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be adding an `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` to your project and add the tables you want to query on from the DB. Then a `.edmx` file is created with your tables and their relations and you can access them in your code (a `DbContext` is created with your db name like `YouDBNameEntities`).

Now that you are connected to the DB, create a new context:

> YourDBNameEntities context = new YourDBNameEntities();

After that you can join on your added tables and in your case self join:

> var Query = context.AddedTable.Join(context.AddedTable, ...)

or

> var Query = from yourClassName1 in context.AddedTable
>
> ```
>          join yourClassName2 in context.AddedTable on yourClass1.ID equals yourClass2.ID
>
>          where !yourClassName1.ParentRole.equals(null)
>
>          select new { ParentRole = yourClassName1.ParentRole }
> ```